# How can I check a sprites position on the x axis during update

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I want to detect what direction the sprite is moving in without using a physics body.

I tried using a physics body as shown below:

```
 if player!.physicsBody!.velocity < 0 {
//Referencing operator function '<' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'CGVector' conform to 
'BinaryInteger' *****
            player! = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftFrameTexture)
        }

        else if player!.physicsBody!.velocity > 0 {
//Referencing operator function '<' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'CGVector' conform to 
    'BinaryInteger' *****
            player! = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrameTexture)
        }
```

but get the error: Referencing operator function '<' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'CGVector' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

There must be an easier way. I don't need any of the physics except for velocity and I wont need velocity if I can tell the direction of the sprite movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is a vector and vectors have a direction but no natural ordering.  If you're interested in just the x-axis and whether the player is moving left or right, you want the x-component of the velocity:

```swift
if player!.physicsBody!.velocity.dx < 0 {
   // Stuff for when the player is moving left
   ...
}
```

Also, you probably don't want to change the player node like `player! = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftFrameTexture)` because you're throwing away everything associated with the player, like the physics body, the location, orientation, scale, etc.  It looks like you just want to change the texture, so:

```swift
if player!.physicsBody!.velocity.dx < 0 {
   player!.texture = leftFrameTexture
} ...
```

Comment: your a hero, thanks for the added clarification / explanation

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check the x position of the sprite in the update?

```
private var timeCheck: Double = 0
private var lastPosX: CGFloat!

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if timeCheck == 0 {

        timeCheck = currentTime
        lastPosX = someSprite.position.x
        return
    }

    //check 10 times a second versus 60 
    if currentTime - currentTime > 0.1 {

        let xDif = someSprite.position.x - lastPosX 

        if xDif == 0 {
           //not moving
        }
        else if xDif < 0 {
            //moving left
        }
        else {
            //moving right
        }

        timeCheck = currentTime
        lastPosX = someSprite.position.x
    }

}
```